# Should a NoSQL (dynamodb) table be denormalized if data needs to be queried independently?

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql, amazon-dynamodb, database-schema

I have a simple API for recording / querying workouts and their associated exercises, created using AWS Lambda / API Gateway / Dynamodb. I expect that my question is equally applicable to other NoSQL databases also, e.g. Mongodb.

The basic structure is simple: there is a one-to-many relationship between workouts and exercises, so from the perspective of the API `/workouts/{id}` returns the workout as a JSON object, and `/workouts/{id}/exercises` returns the exercises that belong to the workout. I would also like `/exercises?exerciseTypeID={exerciseTypeID}` to return all exercises of a particular type, e.g. `/exercises?exerciseTypeID=4xBT` should return all running exercises.

When structuring this data in dynamodb, it seems that I have two choices: denormalize by nesting the exercises within the workout object, as below:

Workout (denormalized):

```
'id': '8977-9823-QbUU',
    'name': 'Marathon training',
    'date': '22-08-2015',
    'exercises': {
        '1112-0120-XaBt': {
            'name': 'Warmup',
            'exerciseTypeID': '4xBT', # Running
            'distance': '2500', # meters
            'speed': '9', # km/h
            'duration': 1000 # seconds
         },
         '2253-4288-TKhg': {
             'name': '10K practice',
             'exerciseTypeID': '4xBT', # Running
             'distance': '10000',
             'speed': '11',
             'duration': 3272 # seconds
         }

    }

}
```

Or alternatively, normalize the schema and store exercises in a separate table, linked to the workout by `workoutID`, as below:

Workout (normalized):

```
{
     'id': '8977-9823-QbUU',
     'name': 'Marathon training',
     'date': '22-08-2015'
}
```

Exercises (normalized):

```
{
     'id': '1112-0120-XaBt',
     'workoutID': '8977-9823-QbUU',
     'name': 'Warmup',
     'exerciseTypeID': '4xBT', # Running
     'distance': 2500, # meters
     'speed': 9, # km/h
     'duration': 1000 # seconds
}

{
     'id':  '2253-4288-TKhg',
     'workoutID': '8977-9823-QbUU',
     'name': '10K run',
     'exerciseTypeID': '4xBT', # Running
     'distance': 10000, # meters
     'speed': 11, # km/h
     'duration': 3272 # seconds
}
```

The primary query for exercises would be to get all exercises associated with a particular workout. On this basis, I should denormalize by storing the exercise data in the workout object, per the first example, so that I would need to perform only a single query to get the workout and all the associated exercises. Alternatively, if I normalize then I would need to perform 2 queries most times that I get a workout since needing to see the exercises in a workout will intuitively be a very common request, i.e. normalized is less efficient for this use case.

The complication comes with needing to also access the exercises directly, independent of the workout (perhaps 10% of the frequency of viewing a workout and its exercises). It seems that this would be slow / expensive in the denormalized schema. For example, if I want to understand how my running times have improved over my last 10 runs (which I could do with the `/exercises?exerciseTypeID={exerciseTypeID}` API call), in the denormalized example I would need to perform an expensive query on all workouts to find `Exercises` with `exerciseTypeID == '4xBT'` since I can't project my nested `workoutTypeID` into a global secondary index as it's not a top-level attribute.

I imagine this can't be a particularly extreme or unusual scenario - am I missing an obvious / easy way to query nested objects that would allow me to stick with the denormalized schema? If not, how do I manage the trade-off between very frequent slightly more expensive database queries (2 queries vs. 1 query) against very frequent very efficient queries most of the time and very slow queries 10% of the time?

Comment: @H O Did you ever solve this problem?

Comment: No, I ended up using a different DB (mongodb) that seemed more suited to the task, since this kind of query is very common in the application.

Answer (score 0):

My thought would be to duplicate the data. Do both. Storage is fairly cheap, so as long as you have a service to do updates / adds, which makes the changes to both tables, this should not effect the cost of running the database and should result in fast query responses. I'm assuming the data doesn't change too often.